# Error in using deployment when using xgboost in Azure App services

Tags: python, azure, azure-web-app-service, xgboost

I am deploying a flask web app with machine learning model trained using xgboost. Working fine on local, giving error when using Azure App services linux machine.

It seems to not installing xgboost properly. I can't troubleshoot it either using their web SSH as it disconnects every few seconds. Any one has any idea how to fix it?

Error:

```
2019-04-05T20:46:57.927633884Z /home/site/wwwroot/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/externals/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py:47: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
2019-04-05T20:46:57.927671786Z   import imp
2019-04-05T20:46:57.927678286Z [2019-04-05 20:46:57 +0000] [39] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2019-04-05T20:46:57.927682786Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-04-05T20:46:57.927686887Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2019-04-05T20:46:57.927691387Z     worker.init_process()
2019-04-05T20:46:57.927695487Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2019-04-05T20:46:57.927700087Z     self.load_wsgi()
2019-04-05T20:46:57.927703987Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2019-04-05T20:46:57.927715888Z     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2019-04-05T20:46:57.927720188Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2019-04-05T20:46:57.927724388Z     self.callable = self.load()
2019-04-05T20:46:57.927728188Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2019-04-05T20:46:57.927732288Z     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2019-04-05T20:46:57.927736189Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2019-04-05T20:46:57.927740389Z     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2019-04-05T20:46:57.927744389Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2019-04-05T20:46:57.927748389Z     __import__(module)
2019-04-05T20:46:57.927752289Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/app.py", line 4, in 
2019-04-05T20:46:57.927756789Z     import xgboost as xgb
2019-04-05T20:46:57.927760690Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xgboost/__init__.py", line 11, in 
2019-04-05T20:46:57.927764990Z     from .core import DMatrix, Booster
2019-04-05T20:46:57.927768990Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xgboost/core.py", line 136, in 
2019-04-05T20:46:57.927773190Z     _LIB = _load_lib()
2019-04-05T20:46:57.927776990Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xgboost/core.py", line 128, in _load_lib
2019-04-05T20:46:57.927781090Z     lib.XGBGetLastError.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
2019-04-05T20:46:57.927784991Z UnboundLocalError: local variable 'lib' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Did you want to deploy your flask app with xgboost model to App Service on Linux? Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-python and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-ssh-support to tell me what you did try.

Comment: I tried the 2nd half of this: Deploy with Azure DevOps builds (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-local-git?toc=%2fazure%2fapp-service%2fcontainers%2ftoc.json).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the xgboost module is not loaded. I would suggest you to have the mpodule imported during startup. In Docker you can do this by specifying the install steps in the docker file.

You can use the steps from the dockerfile of alpine based docker image: https://github.com/Nexosis/alpine-xgboost/blob/master/Dockerfile

BTW, I found this via the discussion on the Github thread: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/3157

**More Info:**
One way to do this would be to fork a copy of the official Python image used in Azure App Service from here: https://hub.docker.com/r/appsvc/python

Once you have this, you can edit the dockerfile in your repo and include the steps from the solution posted above to build your own docker image. This will ensure that you have all the modules loaded.

Comment: I tried the 2nd half of this: Deploy with Azure DevOps builds (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-local-git?toc=%2fazure%2fapp-service%2fcontainers%2ftoc.json). I ultimately created a customer docker, pushed on docker hub and used in App services. Though that wasn't I wanted to do.

Comment: If the app is using any dependencies that are not present in the default docker image, then developing your custom image is a better option to ensure that those dependencies are pre-installed. There are few advantages to this approach, apart from the overhead of maintaining a docker image. 

If the response helped, please upvote the answer.

Comment: Apologies for the late response. Unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem. I had already tried the approach you've given though that's not the one I was looking to use.